# Firefox CSS3 Transition Won't Work

Tags: firefox, css, transition

http://jsfiddle.net/Calum/5dqwJ/

CSS:

```
 textarea {
        height: 20px;
        margin: 20px;
        width: 585px;
        resize: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        vertical-align: top;
        transition: height 3s;
        -webkit-transition: height 3s;
        -moz-transition: height 3s;
        -o-transition: height 3s;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("textarea").focus(function (event) {
         if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
             $(this).height(100);
             $(this).css('resize', 'vertical');
             $(this).attr('placeholder', null);
         }
     });


     $("textarea").blur(function (event) {
         if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
             $(this).height(20);
             $(this).attr('placeholder', "Enter comment");
             $(this).css('resize', 'none');
         }
     });

 });
```

HTML:

```
<textarea placeholder='Enter comment'></textarea>
```

In Chrome, IE and Opera, when you focus on the textarea it expands and contracts with the CSS3 transition.

When I do the same with FireFox, it doesn't animate anything.

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: From the code you posted, the effect is done via jQuery, not via CSS3 Transition.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uTqCd/

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: not quite... setting the height is done by jQuery, but not *the animation to the new height*.  However, good point, maybe what needs to happen is that he needs to use pure css?  There is a `:focus` selector, right?

Comment: Actually, I wonder what the current specifications say about transitions wrt. dynamically setting the height of something.  This might be a point in gray area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the `required` attribute on your textarea, you could use the [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3ainvalid) pseudo-class to target an empty textarea:

```
textarea {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 585px;
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
    -webkit-transition: height .3s;
    -moz-transition: height .3s;
    -o-transition: height .3s;
    transition: height .3s;    
}

textarea:invalid{  /* single line*/
    height: 20px;
    resize: none;
}

textarea:focus{
    height: 100px;
    resize: vertical;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7YAVE)

(add `box-shadow: none;` if you don't want the red border around it)

Comment: Thanks. Especially for the :invalid idea!

Answer (score 3):

see This page for transitions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions

and you can do it completely by css no need to use js

remove **$(this).height(20);** and **$(this).height(100);** From JS and ADD this To css

```
textarea:focus{
   height: 100px;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well,  --> http://jsfiddle.net/FSEqT/

```
textarea:focus {
height: 300px;
margin: 20px;
width: 585px;
resize: none;
overflow: hidden;
vertical-align: top;
}

textarea {
height: 200px;
margin: 20px;
width: 585px;

transition: height 3s;
-webkit-transition: height 3s;
-moz-transition: height 3s;
-o-transition: height 3s;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't animate when focus is lost (which makes sense if you think about it, when it doesn't have focus, it doesn't have a transition rule applied).  Now, I don't know if the OP wants it to only animate only after getting focus or on getting and letting go of focus, so this might be fine, but I suspect OP would want the latter.

Comment: Then inter-change transition effect from the :focus declaration to the generic textarea declaration. See @One Trick Pony answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no css transition in your code. But if you want it, something like below should work. Just add it below `textarea {...}`.

```
textarea:hover {
  height: 100px;
}
```